# Ruby on Rails 3.0 Delayed Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I've added gem 'delayed_job' to my gem file and ran a bundle install.

After that I ran rails generate delayed_job

I've created a controller named Online with a method online.

In turn after the method declaration I added the following line:

handle_asynchronously :online

I start up my app, but the code in that method does not run.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess that you haven't done `rake jobs:work` anywhere. From the [fine manual](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job):

> ### Running the jobs
>
> You can invoke `rake jobs:work` which will start working off jobs. You can cancel the rake task with `CTRL-C`.

You might want to set up [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) to start the Rails server and the Rake task at the same time in your development environment; there's even a Railscast about it:

> http://railscasts.com/episodes/281-foreman

Comment: Maybe delayed job isn't for me. How would I have this constantly running on a production server?

Comment: @Brian: That depends on how your production server is set up.